# How can I rotate this text in canvas html5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have written this code. I had programmed it in pure js,css,html5 before but it looks weird on iDevices so I thought I could make this in canvas easily too. But I ran into following problem.

You can see a condition where I check the angle of the text. I tried multiple things but still can't turn the text upside down on the other side of the "chart". Could anybody help me with that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var orange = "#ef5e09";
  var c = $("#myChart");
  var ctx = c.get(0).getContext("2d");

  var dData = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 90) + 10
  };

  var data = {
    labels: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8", "Item 9", "Item 10"],
    data: [dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData()]
  }

  function draw() {
    //check canvas parent width and calculate dimensions
    c.css("width", c.parent().width());
    c.css("height", c.parent().width());
    ctx.canvas.width = c.parent().width();
    ctx.canvas.height = ctx.canvas.width;
    var d = {
      cX: ctx.canvas.width / 2,
      cY: ctx.canvas.width / 2,
      width: ctx.canvas.width,
      height: ctx.canvas.height,
      lineWidth: ctx.canvas.width * 0.00934579,
      radius: ctx.canvas.width * 0.03,
      cW: ctx.canvas.width * 0.002,
      fW: ctx.canvas.width * 0.28
    };

    // draw bg circles
    for (var i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(d.cX, d.cY, i * d.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      if (i % 2) {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#f6f7f8';
        ctx.fill();
      } else {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
        ctx.fill();
      }
      ctx.lineWidth = d.cW;
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#babbbc';
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    var sa = 2 * Math.PI / data.data.length;
    var font = d.width * (18 / 1000) + 'px Verdana';

    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
      var v = 10 * d.radius * (data.data[i] / 100);
      var nX = d.cX + v * Math.cos(i * sa);
      var nY = d.cY + v * Math.sin(i * sa);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(d.cX, d.cY);
      ctx.lineTo(nX, nY);
      ctx.strokeStyle = orange;
      ctx.lineWidth = d.lineWidth;
      ctx.stroke();

      var l = data.labels[i];

      var nX = Math.floor(d.cX + 11 * d.radius * Math.cos(i * sa));
      var nY = Math.floor(d.cY + 11 * d.radius * Math.sin(i * sa));
      console.log(l + " [" + nX + ":" + nY + "]");
      ctx.save();

      var origAlign = ctx.textAlign;

      if (i * sa > Math.PI / 2 && i * sa < 1.5 * Math.PI) {
      //here's the edited part where I tried to rotate the text in place
      ctx.translate(-ctx.measureText(l).width,d.width*(18/1000)/2);
      ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
      //end of edited part
        ctx.translate(d.cX, d.cY);
        ctx.rotate((10 - i) * sa);
        ctx.font = font;
        ctx.fillStyle = orange;
        ctx.fillText(l, 10.5 * d.radius, 5);
      } else {
        ctx.translate(d.cX, d.cY);
        ctx.rotate((10 - i) * sa);
        ctx.font = font;
        ctx.fillStyle = orange;
        ctx.fillText(l, 10.5 * d.radius, 5);
      }

      ctx.restore();
    }
  }

  draw();
  $(window).resize(draw);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: `ctx.rotate` should be able to put the text upside down. Isn't it?

Comment: sure doing it many times in this snippet already, but please have a look at the code and at the result and see, that whenever I try to rotate the canvas around the point where the text resides it disappears

Comment: `rotate` rotates around (0,0). Translate before and after the rotation to rotate around a different point.

Comment: trust me, tried that thousand times and the text always disappears, if I wasn't trying that for the last two days, I wouldn't post it here yet

Comment: Can you post a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of that attempt?

Comment: For example `ctx.translate(-ctx.measureText(l).width,d.width*(18/1000)/2);`
`ctx.rotate(Math.PI);` 
This was my last attempt. You can put it as first lines of code under where the if begins.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Surely you can trim it down?

Comment: Are you serious right now? the translation just gets to the middle of the text, then rotates it, two lines of code

Comment: I mean the code in your question. The code in your comment isn't self-contained and doesn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Edited the question. Now it "doesn't work" as I described. The text is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When measuring text, you need to set font before measuring text.

When rotating around point (ex. middle of text) that is not origin, you need to translate, rotate, translate.

In your code, try replacing...

```
  if (i * sa > Math.PI / 2 && i * sa < 1.5 * Math.PI) {
  //here's the edited part where I tried to rotate the text in place
  ctx.translate(-ctx.measureText(l).width,d.width*(18/1000)/2);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
  //end of edited part
    ctx.translate(d.cX, d.cY);
    ctx.rotate((10 - i) * sa);
    ctx.font = font;
    ctx.fillStyle = orange;
    ctx.fillText(l, 10.5 * d.radius, 5);
  } else {
```

with...

```
  if (i * sa > Math.PI / 2 && i * sa < 1.5 * Math.PI) {
    ctx.translate(d.cX, d.cY);
    ctx.rotate((10 - i) * sa);
    ctx.font = font;
    ctx.translate(10.5 * d.radius + ctx.measureText(l).width / 2, 0);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
    ctx.translate(-10.5 * d.radius - ctx.measureText(l).width / 2, 0);
    ctx.fillStyle = orange;
    ctx.fillText(l, 10.5 * d.radius, 5);
  } else {
```

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you very much. Never thought that the setting of the font could do so much harm. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to use transformations to rotate text around a centerpoint while keeping the text upright at any angle.

- You can use `context.translate` + `context.rotate` to push the text outward from the centerpoint at an angle.
- You can use `context.scale` to flip the text either vertically or horizontally as needed by the angle.
- You can use `context.textBaseline` to keep the text displaying at a uniform distance from the centerpoint regardless of its angle.

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var angle=0;
var angleIncrement=Math.PI/180;
var count=0;
var cx=75;
var cy=75;
var radius=3;
var PI2=Math.PI*2;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx,cy,3,0,PI2);
ctx.fill();

requestAnimationFrame(animate);


function animate(time){
    var PI2=Math.PI*2;
       
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);   
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,3,0,PI2);
    ctx.fill();
    
    drawLabelAtAngle('Label #'+count,cx,cy,angle,radius);
   
    angle+=angleIncrement;
    angle=(angle+PI2)%PI2;

    count++;
    
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


function drawLabelAtAngle(text,x,y,angle,offset){

    // calc the angle clampled between 0 & PI*2
    var normA=(angle+Math.PI*2)%(Math.PI*2);
    
    // get ready to flip the text if it is on the left side
    if(normA>=Math.PI*3/2 || normA<=Math.PI/2){
        ctx.textAlign='left';
        var flip=1;
        offset+=5;
    }else{
        ctx.textAlign='right';
        var flip=-1;
        offset-=10;
        
    }
    
    // set the baseline to middle
    ctx.textBaseline='middle';

    // set [0,0] to [x,y]
    ctx.translate(x,y);

    // rotate 
    ctx.rotate(angle);

    // if the text is on the left side, flip it for readability
    ctx.scale(flip,flip);

    // draw the text
    ctx.fillText(text,offset,0);

    // always clean up! 
    // reset transforms & text styling
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=150 height=150></canvas>
```

Comment: Great example, thank you very much. Even though your answer could help me with my problem, answer from @Bobby Orndorff solved my problem much quicker. Thank you really a bunch!

Comment: @jPO. Glad you got it sorted :-) Good luck with your project!